# nodejs expressjs route with parameters callback not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the code below, I am hoping to gain the functionality of being able to hit the URLS: `localhost:3000/verify`, `localhost:3000/verify/<value>` and `localhost:3000/verify?hmac=<value>`

However, with this code, the only one that works is the middle option. What am I doing wrong to make this routing work the way I would expect it to?

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.send('Hello World!');
});



//add parameter routing
app.param('hmac', function(req, res, next, hmacvalue) {

    console.log("HMAC route hit " + hmacvalue);
    return next();

});

app.get('/verify/:hmac',function(req,res,next) {
    console.log("I'm in the verify route");
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, did you add routes for the other two, or is this the only route? If the latter, that route clearly doesn't match all three options, only the middle one?

Comment: This is the extent of my code. I am more or less following the code here: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param in the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there are no routes defined that meet the criteria you are looking for. The route `/verify/:hmac` is different than the route `/verify`. The former is searching for a pattern expecting a value in place of `:hmac`.

Try the following

```
app.get('/verify',function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("I'm in the /verify route!");
    console.log(req.query.hmac + " I am the /verify?hmac=<>!");
});
```

Consider reading the Express routing documentation here: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: Ok - I can give this a try. What am I missing about the intended use of app.param then?

Comment: I've used `app.param` when I needed more of a "catch-all" type thing when I was dealing with multiple routes with similar parameters. It's unnecessary in your case and I don't use it often.

Answer (score 0):

The route `/verify/:hmac` only matches URL's of the format `localhost:3000/verify/<value>`.

If you want to catch all the URL's, you have to add routes for them

```
app.get('/verify', function(req, res, next) {

    if ( req.query && req.query.hmac ) {
        console.log( 'localhost:3000/verify?hmac=<value>' );

        var hmac = req.query.hmac;
    } else {
        console.log('localhost:3000/verify');
    }
});

app.get('/verify/:hmac', function(req, res, next) {
    var hmac = req.params.hmac;
});
```